# Magento 2.4 page broken layout

Tags: layout, magento2.4

I'm facing issue with page layout in Magento 2.4.x

Right now I have created a test page in a test module.

Followed all necessary steps to show some text on the page with default theme. I see the output but with broken page layout.

I wonder what I did wrong in the process.

Please advice.

Module files as below

Route: Tadawi\Helloworld5\etc\frontend\routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="helloworldroute" frontName="helloworld">
            <module name="Tadawi_Helloworld5"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Controler: Tadawi\Helloworld5\Controller\Index\Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Tadawi\Helloworld5\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory  */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage =$this->resultPageFactory->create();              
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Layout file :Tadawi\Helloworld5\view\frontend\layout\helloworldroute_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Tadawi\Helloworld5\Block\Index" name="helloworld.index" template="Tadawi_Helloworld5::index.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Template file : Tadawi\Helloworld5\view\frontend\templates\index.phtml

```
<h2>Hello World</h2>

<p>Hello and welcome!</p>
```

This is the output that I'm getting if I call the route

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this file block file also that you mentioned in this.

Or You can simple add '\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' instead of class

Also try to run below command and then check

php bin/magento se:up
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f

May be this will help you to solve your problem.